# 3,8 Volt to 1 Volt via Voltage Divider

Tags: voltage-divider, esp8266

I am trying to get an analog reading from a YL-69 Soil Moisture Sensor onto my ESP8266-12F Module.
The ESP8266 12F is powered via 3 AAA 1,2 (so 3,8 Volt when fully charged) Volt Batteries.
The YL-69 Moisture Sensor and the Controller Board need min. 3,3 Volt.

The ESP8266 12F's analog pin is only capable of reading 0-1 Volt. Reading the analog pin gets me 1024 every time no matter what conditions are present. so I tried a voltage divider with 1x 200 Ohm and 1x 100 Ohm resistor to bring down 3,8 to max. 1,18 Volt.
It looks like this:
[image]

**Problem**: I am not sure I did the right thing when trying to build a voltage divider. The reading now gives me values between 34 and 36 and that does not change when conditions are changed. Is the setup shown in the picture correct or did I something wrong? Did I use the wrong resistors or did I simply violate the principles of electrical engineering.

**Update:** I tried 2K instead of 200 Ohm and 1 K instead of 100 Ohm and now I get values from 272 to 276.... something's still off... Is my setup correct?

Comment: Could be that you destroyed the input when you put 3.3V on it.

Comment: It could be that 300 Ohm is loading the analog output heavily. Try by putting 1K and 2K instead of 100 and 200. Also, testing the voltage with a multimeter can help.

Comment: I don't think that I destroyed the Input because when removing the resistors I'm getting 1024 again. But thanks for the hint. 1K and 2K instead of 100 and 200... I'm going to try this

Comment: I's be very surprised in that board has a fixed reference on it. As such running it straight from the battery will result in a variation in the output as the batteries sag. You really ought to power it from a regulated 3.3V. Not that that is your issue... see larger R values for that, bigger is better.. 10k 20k would even do.

Comment: So what I am trying to do is a reading every 6 Hours or so and than get into deep sleep. I've been using this method on some other sensors and the batteries stay on the same level for a very long time since the deep sleep is extremely efficient in my opinion

Comment: Also see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjJW0_VET8I It's not for the ESP8266, though.

Comment: You could buffer the analogue signal with a voltage-follower circuit first, to provide high input impedance just like and ADC does and then use a voltage divider to scale down the signal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The device you have does not provide an analog output- it is a simple resistance comparator (bridge circuit into an LM393 inputs):

[image]

Since the [LM393](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/group1/b4/cc/cf/13/18/28/44/f5/CD00000465/files/CD00000465.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000465.pdf) has an open-collector output, your loading it will cause the LED D2 to turn on and will reduce the voltage substantially.

You can use the output as a logic signal into your micro, but there is no analog signal to work with. The switching threshold is set by R2, and at mid-scale is when the sensor is 10K.

You could try using the sensor alone, but you would have to add a resistor (like R2) and a voltage reference (maybe a 1.25V shunt reference + another resistor) to get a sort-of decent result.

This is a **particularly crappy** moisture sensor since it has DC across the PCB and will not last long. I suggest throwing it in the garbage (by which I mean properly recycling the electronics which probably has lead) and looking for something better.

---

Edit:

The output impedance at the 'AC' pin is from 10K to much less, depending on the sensor state. The input impedance of the ESP seems to be fairly high, so you could try  100K+200K with a cap like 10n to ground. However the reading will vary directly with Vcc as others have noted.

Note that you will not be using the board at all except for R1.

So U1, D1/R3, R2 and maybe D2/R4 will serve only to drain your battery.

If you want to add a reference, a [MCP1501](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005474D.pdf) with a single resistor replacing R1 would do a much better job and will not vary with battery voltage. It does not require an output capacitor (and should not have a large capacitor added), but a small cap on the input would not hurt. Put the resistor near the reference *not* near the sensor if you are running any length of wire. Since you would then have a 0-1V output you could dispense with the divider.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I'm fully aware that this sensor is a piece of sh**. The thing that kept me going was that I initially used that sensor with an NodeMCU board that hosts an ESP8266 12 E (i think) Module as well. When I connected everything without any resistor everything worked flawlessly and I got good Sensor readings ranging from 300 to 1023. I was trying to get the same result with a simple. naked ESP8266 12 F module and did not get it to work. Right now I'm not really considering the sensor for a reliable project but I'm eager to get the same reading as with the NodeMCU

Comment: @PeterS Please see edit above.

Comment: Thank you very much... so to comprehend since I'm fairly new to this whole stuff: I could get rid of the controller board, use an MCP1501 with some small capacitor on the input and would end up with some viable readings until the sensor itself falls apart. I also found an explanation on why this worked with an NodeMCU https://www.letscontrolit.com/wiki/index.php/DC_Voltage_divider

Comment: Yes, plus a 10K resistor to replace R1.